# empty data in ajax call to mvc action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net mvc. I have this action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyData myData)
{
   .... // For some reason data is always empty. The attributes are all null
}
```

MyData is:

```
public class MyData {
    public string prop1 {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<int> prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

I am calling it this way:

```
   var specificData = { prop1: 'abc', prop2: [1,2,3] }

   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/MyController/Create',
        data: { myData: specificData }, //data contains the same attributes as MyData class
        success: function (data, b,c,d) {
            alert("success!");
        },
        error: function (data, b, c, d) {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
```

The problem is that inside the Create action the "data" variable is instantiated but it's attributes are all null. Am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**
According to @Rory McCrossan I solve it by using `data: specificData` instead of `data: { myData: specificData }`. But now I have this problem in a different place. The serialization problem related to MyData class because now I am using more complex class:
    public class Person {
        public string name{get;set;}
    }

```
public class MyData {
    public string prop1 {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Person> prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

and specificData is:

```
var specificData = { prop1: 'abc', 
                     prop2:  [ 
                         {name:'a'},
                         {name:'b'},
                         {name:'c'}]
                   };
```

In the action, myData.prop2.ElementAt(0).name is null.
What is wrong now?

Comment: Can you please post the content of your `data` variable. Also, a list of the properties of your `MyData` class would help.

Comment: I think problem is using variable data, can you please change it

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: I updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the JS object to send, you are wrapping the properties in a `myData` property which is not required. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    data: specificData
    // other settins...
});
```

Comment: Are you sure? As far as I know if a web service require myData parameter, then the data should be {myData:{/*data here*/}}. Is this different with mvc?

Comment: @Naor My initial thoughts were incorrect - I updated my answer. This should work for you now.

Comment: You right, this is workd for me but not for a class that contains a complex array. The array returns with elements but the elements are not filled. I updated my question. What is wrong?